# IE11 not able to get the the current URL using document.location.href OR $(location).attr("href")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have to add an anchor tag which when clicked reloads the current page (anchor tag contains the current url)

```
document.getElementById('clickhere').innerHTML='<div>Something went Wrong! <a href=""'+$(location).attr("href")+'>Click here to reload</a> </div>';
```

When I click on the anchor tag in chrome, the page loads fine. As per the screenshot when I hover over the link, it shows the full URL. After /private I am able to see the other part of URL.

[image]

Below screenshot when I executed the page in IE11. If I check, the part after /private is not present.

[image]

I am not able to get why the difference. I have added this code in the Jquery AJAX success section. Also tried using Javascript's **document.location.href** but still the same problem.

Comment: what is dolar `$(location)`

Comment: if you do a $(location).attr("href") , it will get the current browser/tab URL

Comment: In your code has something wrong. About: 
`<a href=""'+$(location).attr("href")+'>Click here to reload</a> </div>`
Change to: 
`<a href="'+$(location).attr("href")+'">Click here to reload</a> </div>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @NguyenVQ the syntax you provided worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with:

```
windows.location.href
```

```js
document.getElementById('clickhere').innerHTML='<div>Something went Wrong! <a href="' + window.location.href + '">Click here to reload</a> </div>';
```

```html
<div id='clickhere'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

click active x control button and  your script is load and you can use both line work

1- document.getElementById('clickhere').innerHTML='Something went Wrong! Click here to reload ';

2- $('#clickhere').html('Something went Wrong! Click here to reload ');